# TeX Interpreter in Matlab uiTable

Tags: matlab, tex, matlab-uitable

I have created an uiTable in Matlab. Now I need to write column headers and some cell data, which contain greek letters and subscripts. In text objects or plots I would just enable the TeX interpreter - or it is even the default setting. This does not work in an uiTable. How would I do this here? Maybe pre-formatting the strings somehow?

If there would be a solution, the next question will be: I need this interpreter only in some cells (and column headers). Some other need to be printed as the strings are given. So basically, I would even need an individual TeX interpreter setting per cell. But I know this would be solvable by the correct string escaping...

Minimal example:

```
h = figure();
t=uitable(h);
set(t,'ColumnName',{'test_1';'\alpha'})
```

[This looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDc7t.png) But it should be rather with an index "1" and an alpha character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html and unicode char to do what you want in the column headers.

You could use [the str2html FEX submission](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46755-str2html) to create the html and you need to know the unicode char for the greek letters:

```
h = figure();
t=uitable(h);

str = str2html ( 'test', 'subscript', '1' );
set(t,'ColumnName',{str; char(945)})


Note: the html in this example is: <HTML>test<sub>1</sub></HTML>
```

This produces:

[image]

You can use the same theory to display in the individual cells:

```
h = figure();
t=uitable(h);

str = str2html ( 'test', 'subscript', '1' );
Data{2,2} = str;
Data{3,3} = str2html ( 'test', 'superscript', '2' );
Data{4,1} = str2html ( '90', 'superscript', char(176) );
set(t,'ColumnName',{str; char(945); char(946)},'Data', Data)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect solution! Thank you! Just a small downside: the char() method does not work - it outputs the correct string in the Matlab command window, but not in the table. Here I see only spaces where the greek letters should be. But of course I could set Greek letters with HTML too. Didn't know about this neat feature of HTML interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the str2html trick!
For simple unicode symbols I came to this solution:

```
strUnicodeChar = char(hex2dec( '21C4' ));
```

That will give symbol of ⇄.

Unicodes can be found here 
https://unicode-table.com/de/#21C4